# Are Android Device ID's case sensitive?

Tags: android, android-identifiers, deviceid

I have get my device IDs from the system all in lower case letters. Some Device ID app in PLayStore return the device IDs in upper case only. I've heard that these kind of IDs for **iOS are case sensitive**.

**Are Android device IDs case sensitive?**

I appreciate link with documentation as well.

EDIT: To be more precise, as you can see [here](http://st1.vchensubeswogfpjoq.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Get-Device-ID-Example-in-Android-300x438.png), the device ID was read

**f07a13984eed116a**

is that the same device as

**F07A13984EED116A**
? Or is the last one another device?

Comment: Do you mean the IMEI or the ANDROID_ID?

Comment: Yes, they are case sensitive. But what are you using Device ID for? If it's for some kind of registration purpose may i suggest using INSTANCE ID and not Device ID.

Comment: @Bradan Not IMEI, I mean ANDROID_ID

Comment: @BhaveshMisri I miss the explanation why case sensitive..

Comment: As described in my answer it is a hex string of a long value, and therefore f07a13984f6d116a is equal to F07A13984F6D116A, but I was using ANDROID_ID, not getDeviceId(). I'll look that one up, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/625239a/packages/SettingsProvider/src/com/android/providers/settings/SettingsProvider.java#598) on line 598, the [ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) is a hexadecimal string. Thus, the case does not matter and it is case insensitive.

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) also states that it is a hex string.

[UPDATE]

There is another function: [getDeviceId](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()) in TelephonyManager. It reads the IMEI, MEID or ESN, depending on what your phone's hardware delivers to you. The [IMEI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Station_Equipment_Identity) is decimal, [MEID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_equipment_identifier) is hexadecimal, the [ESN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_serial_number) is either decimal or hexadecimal. However, only the value behind is important to distinguish devices, so it is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

"A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated"
This is the comment in the source code.

Hex strings are NOT case-sensitive , hence it is the same device